Avoiding circular dependency when an app depends on library headers but library depends on app
I have a C++ project with the following directory structure :
MyProject
    include
        App.hpp
    src
        App.cpp
    apps
        Gizmo
            Gizmo.hpp
            Gizmo.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
    CMakeLists.txt

The desired behavior is that the library MyLib exposes some headers App.hpp with classes for apps to inherit from. But I also want some apps to come with the library "batteries included". How can I link Gizmo against MyLib so that it can access the public headers and link MyLib against Gizmo so that it can be used from within the library?
MyProject/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(MyLib SHARED ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/App.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include}
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/apps/Gizmo)

MyProject/apps/Gizmo/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(Gizmo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Gizmo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Gizmo PRIVATE MyLib)
target_include_directories(Gizmo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})


target_include_directories(Gizmo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include) .... you have a serious levelization problem, circular dependency shouldn't appear with good planning, something depending on something above it is poor planning, the dependencies of Gizmo should apear below it in the dependency graph, not above it.

@AhmedAEK thanks - do you have a better suggestion for organizing a project where the library exposes public headers but can also link against its customers? This pattern is common in a plugin system, where a library will expose headers for plugins to implement but may also come with some builtin plugins.

you can make a fake CMake library that just exposes the headers, (an INTERFACE library), and both MyLib and Gizmo will depend on it, if you have many plugins they can all share this common base dependency, this at least solves the levelization problem for plugins.

@AhmedAEK I gave that a shot but I can't build Gizmo because it is missing the symbols from MyLib since it just has the headers exposed through the fake interface library.

Your headers need to only expose interfaces that don't require linking, otherwise you need to convert that library from header-only into an actual library, an interface that doesn't require linking only imlements a virtual destructor in the header that does nothing, and the rest of the virtual methods should be =0, this way it doesn't require linking, and any non-virtual method should be implemented in the header. example: https://godbolt.org/z/4E77PshPf

library should not depend on app.
